# How to access the visited vertices in a given shortest path using R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I use `all_shortest_paths` function to identify all the shortest paths for given two vertices.

I do not know the differences, but the following two functions give me the same results

```
all_shortest_paths(g, 1,3)
get.all.shortest.paths(g, 1,3)
```

Here is the outcome

```
$res
$res[[1]]
+ 3/9 vertices, from a86e634:
[1] 1 4 3

$res[[2]]
+ 3/9 vertices, from a86e634:
[1] 1 2 3


$nrgeo
[1] 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1
```

Now, I want to get the nodes that are visited in a path without the source and sink nodes. For instance, I get the first shortest path.

```
> all_shortest_paths(g, 1,3)$res[1]
[[1]]
+ 3/9 vertices, from a86e634:
[1] 1 4 3`
```

How can I store the nodes that are visited excluding the source and sink nodes (i.e., 1,3)? When I assign `a<- all_shortest_paths(g, 1,3)$res[1]`, its type seems like list, but no matter what I am doing, I cannot access 4. It keeps returning me `+ 3/9 vertices, from a86e634:
[1] 1 4 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go one more level down the list returned by `all_shortest_paths`. In the code below I create the variable `n` to make it more readable.

```
library(igraph)

g <- make_graph("Cubical")

p <- all_shortest_paths(g, 1, 3)

n <- length(p[[1]][[1]])
p[[1]][[1]][-c(1, n)]
#+ 1/8 vertex, from 0de75ff:
#[1] 4
```

To get all inner vertices in one go, use `lapply` on `p[[1]]`.

```
lapply(p[[1]], function(.p){
  n <- length(.p)
  .p[-c(1, n)]
})
#[[1]]
#+ 1/8 vertex, from 0de75ff:
#[1] 4
#
#[[2]]
#+ 1/8 vertex, from 0de75ff:
#[1] 2
```

This code does not depend on the number of inner vertices, as can be seen if the source and sink are 1 and 7.
This time a one-liner.
(Output omitted.)

```
p2 <- all_shortest_paths(g, 1, 7)

lapply(p2[[1]], function(.p) .p[-c(1, length(.p))])
```

Comment: That's a really smart way to do it! Thanks.